# Problem exporting Excel as csv to another location, vba - window "blacks out"

Tags: excel, vba

I have had some problems with exporting an Excel document as a CSV. I got help with the following code, but the problem I get is that the document "blacks out" and gets irresponsive after.

I want my users to be able to continue to work on the file after.

```
 Sub ExportAsCSV()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim folderPath As String, csvFile As String
folderPath = "C:\test"
If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir folderPath
 csvFile = folderPath & "\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".csv"

    

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` is this code in the workbook you are closing or a different one? You should assign your workbooks to variables, instead of using `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: How many workbooks are there? There is the workbook containing this code and...? Which one do you want to save in the `.csv` format?

Comment: It is only one workbook. what is it I am misunderstanding?

Comment: You cannot export the workbook if you have closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export As CSV (Overwrite and Save)

- Adjust the two values in the constants section.
- Note that this will overwrite the `.csv` file if it already exists.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportAsCSV()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\test"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir FolderPath
    End If
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & Split(wb.Name, ".")(0)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Will reset after `End Sub`.
    wb.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Enables overwrite without dialog popup.
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

- The following will export the active sheet and leave the workbook saved and open. Now you can continue to work in it.

**Export Worksheet**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportAsCSV()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\test"
    
    If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir FolderPath
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sName As String: sName = swb.ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & Split(swb.Name, ".")(0)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    swb.Save
    swb.ActiveSheet.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Overwrite without dialog popup.
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Worksheet '" & sName & "' exported.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I have screwed up big time now. The code is working as intended when exporting to a file location on the hard drive. I've been using the last couple of hours to change the location from "c:\test to a location on a server. I guess the whole code must be changed then? I have tried `Sub serverfolder() Dim StrFile As String
                 StrFile = Dir("\\ServerIP\Folder\" & "*")
                Do While StrFile <> ""
                 StrFile = Dir`

Answer (score 1):

1. This line `If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir folderPath` is a one-line-if-statement which cannot have an `End If`. So either you need a linebreak after `Then` or remove the `End If`. As it is now it will throw an error.
2. This line `ActiveWindow.Close` closes the workbook. So after that saving it with `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` cannot work anymore because it is already closed! This line needs to be removed.
3. Finally the `Application.DisplayAlerts` are not needed.
4. A `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` without a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` does not make much sense here. So we can remove that too.

So try the following:

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()
    Dim folderPath As String, csvFile As String
    folderPath = "C:\test"
 
    'if your `If` has and `End If` there must be nothing than a linebreak after `Then`
    If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if C:\test does not exist yet
        MkDir folderPath '… create it.
    End If

    csvFile = folderPath & "\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".csv"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'ActiveWindow.Close 'if you close here you cannot save it later because it is closed

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers! I think I get some of what you are explaining, but the code doesn't seem to be working now. First tried changing my current code after your pointers, and then just copy pasting your code, but nothing happens after I press the button.

Comment: Probably because the `folderPath = "C:\test"` already existed. Check out my updated answer. I moved the `End If`. • You might benefit from reading [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and learn how to go through your code step by step to debug it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help. Will definitely  bookmark your suggestion about the debugging :)